# Linux Block Device FileSystem:Store/Save & Load on reboot

Tags: backup, filesystems, mount, file-transfer, ubuntu-16.04

Scenario: Created a Block file system, mounted [mount /dev/sbd0p1 /mnt] and echoe'd[echo Hi > /mnt/file1]
[http://blog.superpat.com/2010/05/04/a-simple-block-driver-for-linux-kernel-2-6-31/comment-page-2/#comment-214357]

Task: I need to copy this mount (or file within the mount) somewhere - Basically, a replica which wont be lost on shut/reboot, that I can rely on instead of the mounted RAM file - So that, On reboot, I should be able to load from this copied mount ( or copied file within the mount) instead of the original in RAM which would be lost on reboot.

Searched a bit, couldnt get much pointers. Can somebody give exact solution please.

Note: Iam not a pro on kernels, need this as an intermediary solution for something else.
Thanks!
-Sree

Comment: *"a Block file system"* -- No such thing.  A filesystem is always based on a block device.  But there is no type of filesystem named *"block"*.  *"this as an intermediary solution for something else"* -- Red flag for possible XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dd to dump the raw filesystem from memory

```
dd if=/dev/sbd0p1 of=/home/user/somefile.raw
```

After that you can mount the file as a filesystem

```
mount -t vfat -o offset=512 somefile.raw /mnt/
```

Comment: Thanks Dr! 
Why not these (from what I skimmed through so far): 
1.cat /dev/mem ram.dat
2.rsync?

Comment: """"....
dd if=/dev/mem of=mem.dump bs=1 skip=10000 count=5000
...to dump 5000 bytes starting at offset 10000. I'm not 100% sure what the effect of reading the /dev/mem like this will be. One thing to watch is that dumping the memory will no doubt affect the memory... so you won't get an instantaneous snapshot. You might do better to dump from a virtual machine, or use a hardware debugger.""""

Dr, Is there any space issue to be considered?

Comment: You shouldn't use cat /dev/mem because you're dumping all the memory that way (in some part of that is the memory correspondig to the disk you created, but you have to find it). For your need using cat or dd is equivalent

Comment: Thanks!!

root@ubuntu3:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sbd0: 512 KiB, 524288 bytes, 1024 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x25007266

/dev/sbd0p1          1  1023    1023 511.5K 83 Linux

root@ubuntu3:~# sudo mount -t auto -o loop,offset=512 /home/ubuntu3/fs.raw /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       - try dmesg | tail or so.

Comment: Tried with "mount -t auto" too as in some forums, but get this " wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0" error!

Comment: don't use the offset parameter. That's for skiping the partition table. My bad

Comment: If that solved your question, please set the question as solved. Regards